# Adding custom roles to Case "Add role" function

Tags: relationships, civicase, roles

I've tried this on a couple of instances, but if I have a Case I want to add role to, the list is restricted to the core roles that come with CiviCRM and none of my custom roles based on custom relationships show up in the list.

How can I set it up so my users can add more roles than offered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CiviCRM versions 4.5 and above, you can add case roles by navigating to **Administer -> CiviCase -> Case Types** and clicking "Add Role"

[image]

Note that roles and relationships are not precisely the same. A case client can have any relationships, but within the case, only the roles you have defined will be available.

Answer (score 2):

In CiviCRM versions 4.4 and below, you need to configure the additional roles by modifying the XML file for your case type, per [the documentation](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC44/CiviCase+Configuration).